# docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Using a fresh Docker desktop (2.3.0.5) installation on Windows 10, I am not able to pull any image. I get this error :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF
```

I am behind a corporate proxy, so I've tried configuring it :

- with credentials, following http://domain\username:password@proxy-url.com:port format
- like above, but with special characters encoded : https://www.url-encode-decode.com/
- without credentials
- with http/https
- without http/https

but nothing seems to work..

There's really not much help in the logs : what else can I try ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since we can configure a proxy for http and http**s**, I had put what I thought was the proper value for each, ie :

- http://domain\username:password@proxy-url.com:port
- https://domain\username:password@proxy-url.com:port

(with special characters in the password URL encoded with https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ )

but it wasn't working.. I tried putting the **http** string for both http and http**s**, and it worked ! (I guess the corporate proxy doesn't support https internally)

Comment: This works like charm. If someone wondering where to update, its in the file /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf

Comment: You saved my night :)

Answer (score 4):

Please check the dockerservice configuration `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`, if the configuration file is like this,

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443"
```

Please remove the `https://` and `http://`

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that i was behind a corporate proxy and hence i was unable to reach the registry-1.docker.io.

Solution:

I bypassed this URL registry-1.docker.io in the proxy server for following

SSL bypass
Authentication Bypass.
Then i configured the proxy settings in docker.service file in RHEL server as

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:443"
NO_PROXY=“harbour.company.com,10.xxx.xx.xxx,
registry-1.docker.io/v2/”
```

Make sure the HTTPS_PROXY protocol is http.

By doing this i was able to fetch images.

Comment: For me, it works because of `Make sure the HTTPS_PROXY protocol is http.`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I simply drop my answer here because it works for me.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service
```

It can work in Ubuntu.